# Kub8s Flink TaskManager not reconnecting to the new Jobmanager

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

Setup Flink Kub8s Cluster.

1. JM pod started.
2. TM (Task Manager ) Pod giving below error.

---

```
2020-10-31 11:08:54,895 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                   [] - Remote connection to [null] failed with org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: flink-jobmanager/10.96.28.96:6123
2020-10-31 11:08:54,906 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*.
2020-10-31 11:09:14,946 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*.
2020-10-31 11:09:24,946 INFO  akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor                     [] - No response from remote for outbound association. Associate timed out after [20000 ms].
2020-10-31 11:09:24,947 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                       [] - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123]] Caused by: [No response from remote for outbound association. Associate timed out after [20000 ms].]
2020-10-31 11:09:24,956 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                   [] - Remote connection to [null] failed with org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: flink-jobmanager/10.96.28.96:6123
2020-10-31 11:09:24,967 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*.
2020-10-31 11:09:45,006 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*.
```

---

Comment: Have you configured the file `flink-configuration-configmap.yaml` and the others as well accoeding to the documentation at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html ? It might be something wrong with the services and config files. This is my deployment working https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-flink/tree/master/k8s